# Excel 2013 stopped working -- seems to crash on launch - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office, crash

New Toshiba laptop with Windows 8.1 - came with Office 2013 installed.  I had Excel working and edited a few spreadsheets as a test.  Then I set up another user account as Standard and ran some Windows Updates.

Now Excel will not launch.  I've not been able to see it in the process window, however when I pin the shortcut to the task bar I see it highlight for about 4-5 seconds indicating that it is trying to start but then closes.

Word and Powerpoint do the same thing!

How can I troubleshoot this?  I'm Windows experienced but 8.1 is new to me.

Update: Loading in /safe mode does not help. I ran Procmon and see that the process loads and does some stuff, but exits within about .2 seconds. Nothing obvious based on the registry and file access to my inexperienced eye...still a puzzle.

Comment: It could be a faulty plug in... Can you load it in safe mode? From command prompt type in `excel /safe`

Comment: I would try Microsoft TechNet they might have more experience of this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar issue when creating additional users on a workstation. Uninstalling and re-installing cured the problem. You may want to use the Microsoft Fix-It tool to get it to completely remove Office 2013 and other remnants. Not ideal but Microsoft really haven't thought about the product.